# Brother MFC-L2710DN printer and scanner for Ubunto18.04 - How to install?

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, brother

I have the multi-functional printer/scanner [Brother MFC-L2710DN](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl2710dn_eu).
But I cannot install its drivers on my computer with Ubuntu 18.04.

The USB-cable is connected.
I could not find drivers for MFC-L2710 in the table from Brother for Ubuntu.
What driver could I take for this device?

Comment: I wanted to add a link to a description of your printer, but I may accidently have added more than that...

Comment: Go to: https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcl2710dn_eu Update your question if you have any issues following the instructions there.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your quick answers.
I solved the problem by installing

```
sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1
```

I went through all possible tutorials several times, but nothing helped but the installation [of this Brother support entity](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=mfcl2710dn_eu&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625).

This solved the problem.

I suspect a possible USB port corruption or lack of support for USB 3.0, because the scanner came to life when I passed it to another USB 2.0 port on my HPG255 laptop.

I will add that Ubuntu was upgraded from an older version on which drivers were already installed with a working scanner (on this port) and a working printer.

Answer (score 0):

This page helped me alot to get printer and scanner to work via network: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Scanner/Brother/

Via USB the scaner ocasionally did not work for me.

The printer works fine via cups alone, but for the scanner the drivers "bscan4" and "bscan-skey" from the brother homepage are required.